# JavaScriptSerializer deserialize returning 0 results list

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Trying to Deserialize json string to a List. Json string is not empty. But after deserialization the list returning 0 items.

This is my class.

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Products : GenericItem
    {
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double SalePrice { get; set; }

        public bool OnSale
        {
            get { return (SalePrice < Price); }
        }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public GenericItem Brand { get; set; }

        public List<GenericItem> Shops { get; set; }

        public string ProductCode { get; set; }

        public Colour Colour { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Colour : GenericItem
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GenericItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Permalink { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my json string.

```
"{\"Products\":[{\"_id\":\"515c151f7be95925d4ee794d\",\"Name\":\"CAT Formation Steel Toe - Boots  BLACK\",\"Description\":\"CAT Formation Steel Toe Boots With heavy-duty hardwearing uppers, high grip rubber outsoles and a steel toe cap, these CAT Formation Steel Toe Boots are perfect for work. CAT Formation Steel Toe Boots are ankle length and fasten with strong laces for a secure fit. The boots are available in black and have a casual multi-panelled trainer-style appearance, as well as CAT branding on the tongue and heel.\",\"ProductCode\":\"D0073\",\"Images\":[\"18000.jpg\",\"18001.jpg\",\"18002.jpg\"],\"Brand\":{\"_id\":\"5142ca0c7be95917acce7755\",\"Name\":\"CAT\",\"Permalink\":\"cat-footwear\"},\"Shops\":[{\"_id\":\"5142ca237be95917acce7999\",\"Name\":\"Mens\",\"Styles\":null,\"Permalink\":\"Mens\"}],\"Permalink\":\"cat-formation-steel-toe-boots-black\",\"Price\":89.99,\"SalePrice\":89.99}]}"
```

This is how I am deserializing the json string.

```
 var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            jss.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            var results = jss.Deserialize<List<Products>>(json);
```

List always returning 0 results.

Could somebody help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is not a list, but an object that have a property Products, that is a list.

You can deserialize it to something like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
...

jss.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Couldn't spot on my mistake.